# Asynchronous object instantiation

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado

How can I make the following object instantiation asynchronous:

```
class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequentHandler):
    def get(self, id):
        # Async the following
        data = MyDataFrame(id)
        self.write(data.getFoo())
```

The `MyDataFrame` returns a `pandas` `DataFrame` object and can take some time depending on the file it has to parse.

Comment: That would need to be implemented in `MyDataFrame`, and its constructor will likely need a complete rewrite in order to take advantage of Tornado's event loop instead of blocking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MyDataFrame()` is a synchronous interface; to use it without blocking you need to do one of two things:

- Rewrite it to be asynchronous.  You can't really make an `__init__` method asynchronous, so you'll need to refactor things into a static factory function instead of a constructor.  In most cases this path only makes sense if the method depends on network I/O (and not reading from the filesystem or processing the results on the CPU).
- Run it on a worker thread and asynchronously wait for its result on the main thread.  From the way you've framed the question, this sounds like the right approach for you.  I recommend the `concurrent.futures` package (in the standard library since Python 3.2; available via `pip install futures` for 2.x).

This would look something like:

```
@tornado.gen.coroutine
def get(self, id):
    data = yield executor.submit(MyDataFrame, id)
    self.write(data.getFoo())
```

where `executor` is a global instance of `ThreadPoolExecutor`.